# collect web page source with python 2.5.2

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-2.5

I am working on an appliance using an old version of `python (2.5.2)`.

I'm working on a script which needs to read a webpage, but I can't access the normal libraries
 - `urllib`, `urllib2` and requests are not available.

How did people collect this in the olden days?

I could do a `wget/curl` from the `shell`, but I'd prefer to stick to python if possible. I also need to be able to go through a proxy which may force me into system calls.

Comment: why do you have to use old python?

Comment: Its an old load balancer, and its not mine to upgrade

Comment: How do you mean unavailable? `urllib` is still there for Python 2.5.2, according to the docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-urllib.html

Comment: Well it's not in the standard library. I can't do import urllib. I might be able to bundle the files for urllib in the same directory if it can run with python 2.5.x

Comment: Well, I suppose it could be in the standard library, and my appliance is using a stripped back version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it old-school entirely within Python but without urllib, then you'll have to use socket and implement a tiny subset of HTTP 1.0 to fetch the page. Jumping through the hoops to get through a proxy will be really painful though.

Use wget or curl and save yourself a few days of debugging.